# Is there an algorithm that could be used to solve the following problem?

Tags: algorithm, matching

The following scenario is an oversimplification of the problem I'm trying to solve:

Let's assume that we have 10 people and 5 taxis. Each person can choose from 1 to 5 taxis and can only be placed inside a taxi that they have chosen. Each taxi can fit 3 people in it.

Is there an optimal algorithm that matches the people with the taxis and has the minimum amount of people left without any taxi instead of just looping through the people and placing them on the first available choice?

Comment: Are there no further constraints? - it seems it should matter where people wish to go.

Comment: Seems like a max-flow problem.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I don't think any more constraints are necessary. I mean one could choose taxis #1 and #2 and the another #1 #2 and #3. Every person decides for themselves and then I'd like to get as many of them as I can into one of their desired taxis. Maybe a matchmaking algorithm could help but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user3386109 after watching a 5 minute video to get an idea of what max-flow is I think it might work in this case. I'll give it a try tomorrow and see if anything comes out of it.

Comment: Sounds good. The key is to set the edge weights correctly. From the source to each person: 1. From a person to each taxi they like: 1. From each taxi to the sink: 3. So the [flow diagram looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJflC.png).

Comment: In choosing 1 to 5 taxis, each person has chosen 3-15 acceptable seats.  Find a maximum bipartite matching between the people and their acceptable seats.

Comment: @user3386109 I did some tests and it seems to work great as it correctly returns the max flow of the diagram I'm using. However I've got one more question: would it be possible to get all the matches as well (who is matched to which taxi) or should I use another approach for that?

Comment: Okay, so I ended up using this [library](https://pypi.org/project/hopcroftkarp/) that does exactly what I was looking for using the Hopcroft Karp’s Algorithm. Thank you all for the suggestions!

Comment: Hopcroft Karp is probably the best solution. Well done. fwiw, the answer to your previous question is that the list of edges should have a flow and a capacity assigned to each edge. After finding the total flow, you can scan the list of edges. An edge between a person and a taxi that has a flow of 1 assigns that person to that taxi.